# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have this angularjs function:

```
var ajax = (function () {
    var ajax = function () { };
    ajax.get = function (_url) {
        var _data = '';
        $http({
            url: _url,
            method: "GET",
            data: _data
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    }
})();
```

When call this function:

```
ajax.get("http://www.test.com/request");
```

I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

On top level you have this `var ajax = (function () {...})()`, which is IIF that doesn't return anything, which means your ajax will be undefined. You would like to return created ajax object from within your IIF.

Try something like this

```
var ajax = (function () {
 var ajax = function () { };
 ajax.get = function (_url) {
    var _data = '';
    $http({
        url: _url,
        method: "GET",
        data: _data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
}
return ajax;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! But I get `$http is not defined`

Comment: You could try to pass $http service into your IIF, it could look like this:

Comment: `var ajax = (function ($http) {...})($http)`, if it is in scope of highest level ajax variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start here:

```
var ajax = function () { };
```

ajax is not an object it is a function which is why you can not do this assignment

```
 ajax.get = function (_url) {
    var _data = '';
    $http({
        url: _url,
        method: "GET",
        data: _data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
}
```

If you want to do it you shold declare variable like this:

```
var ajax = {};
```

Now to the bigger picture:

```
var ajax = (function () {
var ajax = { };
ajax.get = function (_url) {
    var _data = '';
    $http({
        url: _url,
        method: "GET",
        data: _data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
}
})();
```

**You can't access function variables**, and even if you could you should have done it like this (**which is still incorrect of course**):

```
ajax.ajax.get("http://www.test.com/request");
```

Try this:

```
var ajax = { };
ajax.get = function (_url) {
    var _data = '';
    $http({
        url: _url,
        method: "GET",
        data: _data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
 }
};
```

And access it:

```
ajax.get("http://www.test.com/request");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still get `Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
            var ajax = function() {};
            ajax.get = function(_url) {
              console.log(1)
            }
          })();
```

does note return a value so ajax is undefined, then you are calling undefined of get.

```js
    var ajax = (function() {
      var ajax = function() {};
      ajax.get = function(_url) {
        console.log(1)
      }
    })();


    console.log(
      (function() {
        var ajax = function() {};
        ajax.get = function(_url) {
          console.log(1)
        }
      })()
    )
     ajax.get("http://www.test.com/request");
```